# Identifying the sound card to which the internal microphone belongs

Tags: audio

How can we identify the sound card to which the internal microphone belongs if a pc has more than one sound card and the output from:

`~ $ cat /proc/asound/cards` is:

```
0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xb5610000 irq 47
1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xb5614000 irq 46
```

Comment: It doesn't belong to anything with "HDMI" in the name for sure because that's output only.

Comment: Either use trial and error (and e.g. `arecord`), or have a look at `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` and identify the internal mic by the values on the Pin Complex (read up on it if you're not familiar with the Codec structure). Carefully, sometimes the BIOS lies and those values are not initialized correctly, so you are back to trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

for list of ALSA audio capture devices

`arecord -l`

for Pulseaudio capture source

`pactl list sources`